# java.security.NoSuchProviderException: no such provider: SunMSCAPI

Tags: java, windows, security

I have several programs that use `SunMSCAPI` to read web pages that require an SSL certificate.  My code works under Windows XP (32 bit) but does not work under my fresh installation of Windows 7 (64 bit).  Here is the piece of code:

```
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStoreProvider", "SunMSCAPI");
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStoreType", "WINDOWS-MY");
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStoreProvider", "SunMSCAPI");
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStoreType", "WINDOWS-ROOT"); 
System.setProperty("proxyHost", "proxy");
System.setProperty("proxyPort", "8080");

URL url = new URL(TEST_URL);
try {
    HttpsURLConnection httpsCon = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();....
```

And here is the stack trace:

```
Caused by: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: Error constructing implementation (algorithm: Default, provider: SunJSSE, class: com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.DefaultSSLContextImpl)
 at java.security.Provider$Service.newInstance(Unknown Source)
 at sun.security.jca.GetInstance.getInstance(Unknown Source)
 at sun.security.jca.GetInstance.getInstance(Unknown Source)
 at javax.net.ssl.SSLContext.getInstance(Unknown Source)
 at javax.net.ssl.SSLContext.getDefault(Unknown Source)
 at javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.getDefault(Unknown Source)
 at javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection.getDefaultSSLSocketFactory(Unknown Source)
 at javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection.<init>(Unknown Source)
 at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.<init>(Unknown Source)
 at sun.net.www.protocol.https.Handler.openConnection(Unknown Source)
 at sun.net.www.protocol.https.Handler.openConnection(Unknown Source)
 at java.net.URL.openConnection(Unknown Source)
 at GetData2.SetVallues(GetData2.java:56)  *// HttpsURLConnection httpsCon = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();* 
 ... 2 more
Caused by: java.security.NoSuchProviderException: no such provider: SunMSCAPI
 at sun.security.jca.GetInstance.getService(Unknown Source)
 at sun.security.jca.GetInstance.getInstance(Unknown Source)
 at java.security.Security.getImpl(Unknown Source)
 at java.security.KeyStore.getInstance(Unknown Source)
 at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.DefaultSSLContextImpl.getDefaultKeyManager(Unknown Source)
 at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.DefaultSSLContextImpl.<init>(Unknown Source)
 at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Unknown Source)
 ... 15 more
```

I've tried also following example http://muhammadhamed.blogspot.com/2010/04/accessing-ms-certificate-stores-in-java.html but again received this `NoSuchProviderException`.  My guess is that there is some configuration error but I'm not sure what it is.

Here is my JVM information:
`java version "1.6.0_23"`
`Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_23-b05)`
`Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 19.0-b09, mixed mode)`

I hope somebody will be able to help me :-)

Best regards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [J2SE Security page](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/J2SE/security/) only says that the MS CryptoAPI (which SunMSCAPI uses) is only available under Java 6 on 32-bit Windows.

Luckily, you can still install the 32-bit JVM on Win64.